# How to use the DummyVecEnv in openai

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

I am new to the field of reinforcement learning, I came across these two lines of code

```
env = gym.make("CartPole-v0")
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])
```

I would like to know the purpose of inputting lambda as an argument into DummyVecEnv()?

Answer (score 0):

`DummyVecEnv` needs to be passed on a function that returns an environment.

You can do it in a long-form manner like this:

```py
def make_env():
    env = gym.make('CarRacing-v0')
    return env 

env = DummyVecEnv([make_env])
```

**This is not pythonic, it is a bit more explicit.**

In python, `lambda` keyword generates a lambda function. It is a small anonymous function, it can take any number of arguments, but can only have one expression.

`lambda arguments : expression`

In the case of `DummyVecEnv`, we can use a lambda function to return an environment with a single line:

```py
env = gym.make('CarRacing-v0')
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda:env])
```

**TLDR:** `DummyVecEnv` needs a function that returns an environment as an argument. Using a lambda function we can return an environment with a single expression.